# display multi-page pdf file as single page files in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a pdf file embedded in a HTML document. Is it possible to display a multi-page pdf file as multiple single page files in html? Something similar to a ppt where each page of the pdf doc is equivalent to a slide.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Google PDF viewer for this purpose. As far as I know it's not an official Google feature (am I wrong on this?), but it works for me very nicely and smoothly. You need to upload your PDF somewhere before and just use its URL:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://example.com/mypdf.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:718px; height:700px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Probably the best approach is to use the PDF.JS library. It's a pure HTML5/JavaScript renderer for PDF documents without any third-party plugins.

Online demo: http://mozilla.github.com/pdf.js/web/viewer.html

GitHub: https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js

Comment: Vahid Taghizadeh - Thanks for the prompt reply. However, if i use the iframe, it displays the entire pdf where i have to scroll to see the different pages. I was wondering if there is a way to display page by page as in the case of ppt slides.

Comment: http://www.a-pdf.com/free-jquery-slider-builder/index.htm check it ! are you want a pdf slider html ?